# React Router DOM: export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: image1]

```
export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_FetchersContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_ViewTransitionContext, UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, redirectDocument, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_usePrompt, unstable_useViewTransitionState, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useBlocker, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)
```

[image: image2]

```
export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_FetchersContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_ViewTransitionContext, UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, redirectDocument, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_usePrompt, unstable_useViewTransitionState, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useBlocker, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)
```

There is an error in React that I don't understand. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Could you provide the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR in ./src/TopScroll.js 31:21-31 export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768210/error-in-src-topscroll-js-3121-31-export-withrouter-imported-as-withroute)

Comment: `withRouter` is no longer in the react-router-dom library